# Disable directory browsing in IIS 6 with Script

Tags: powershell, vbscript, iis-6, adsi

I'm trying to write a script to disable directory browsing on ALL directories /virtual directories and on an IIS website.

I've tried using ADSI in PowerShell but am having a hard time understanding how to enumerate current directories and not sure how to change the property on Directory Browsing to false.

Comment: You need to mess around with webconfig if it's in IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$iis = [ADSI]"IIS://$ComputerName/W3SVC/1/ROOT"

# list directories
$iis.Children | select name,@{n='DirBrowsingEnabled';e={$_.psbase.InvokeGet('EnableDirBrowsing')}}

# disable directory browsing on all directories
$iis.Children | where {!$_.psbase.InvokeGet('EnableDirBrowsing')} | foreach {
    $_.put('EnableDirBrowsing',$false)
    $_.psbase.CommitChanges()
}
```